# what parameter to use to make pytest-sugar to show error testcase

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have been using pytest with pytest-xdist and pytest-sugar together for my unit test and it seems work great but what parameter I can use to have error testcase list out like failed one on summary?
I have tried **-r** but it still does not work
the test command I use
    `$pytest -n 3 -v --tb=short -p no:warnings`

```
 7 passed
  3 failed
     - scripts/testcase.py TestName
     - scripts/testcase.py TestAddress
     - scripts/testcase.py TestPhone
  2 error
   1 skipped
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no pytest-sugar parameters to list errored test cases as failed ones.
Errored tests are handled by pytest and pytest-sugar reports whatever pytest reports, albeit in a beautiful way.

If you want, you can change the execution status of errored test using `node` pytest fixture.